# python move file to another folder, rename if file same name already exist

Tags: python

how to move .dat file to another folder, rename to file(1).dat if same file name exist.
*(1) increase the more file same name exist.

current code:

```
src_fldr = r"C:\OUTBOX" 
dst_fldr = "C:\\OUTBOX\\OUTBOX(Backup)"

path = Path(".")  # current directory
extension = ".dat"

for dat_file in glob.glob(src_fldr+"\\*.dat"):
    shutil.move(dat_file, dst_fldr)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

To move the file without risking of overwriting it, you should check if it exists first, and, if so, add a counter to the filename. [Pathlib's path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) can help you with that:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

src_fldr = Path(r"C:\OUTBOX")
dst_fldr = Path(r"C:\OUTBOX\OUTBOX(Backup)")
extension = ".dat"

for dat_file in src_fldr.glob(f"*{extension}"):
    # copy flag and counter
    copy_finished = False
    copy_counter = 0

    while not copy_finished:
        # try original name at first, add (counter) for next tries
        if copy_counter == 0:
            dst_file = dat_file.name
        else:
            dst_file = f"{dat_file.stem}({copy_counter}){dat_file.suffix}"
        # if file exists, increment counter and try again
        if (dst_fldr/dst_file).exists():
            copy_counter += 1
            continue
        # else, move the file (with or without counter) to the new destination
        shutil.move(dat_file, dst_fldr/dst_file)
        # quit while loop
        copy_finished = True
```

Philosophical question: Is *moving* a file to another location really a backup?